# Spring Boot integration test ignoring secure=false in AutoConfigureMockMvc annotation, get 401

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, tdd, spring-data-rest

Can't make my `@SpringBootTest` work. It says authentication is on, which I do not want.

I've set it up with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)`

I submit a mock request with some JSON and my integration test should test the whole stack, taking it through the web layer with SDR to JPA and then into the in-memory database, so I can test for it using `JdbcTemplate`.

But the response is `401`, requires authentication. Why isn't the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)` enough? What's missing?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = { TestDataSourceConfig.class })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@Transactional
public class SymbolRestTests  {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private SymbolRepository symbolRepository;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;  

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateEntity() throws Exception {

        String testTitle = "TEST.CODE.1";
        String testExtra = "Test for SymbolRestTests.java";
        String json = createJsonExample(testTitle, testExtra, true);
        log.debug(String.format("JSON==%s", json));
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
                post("/symbols").content(json);
        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().string("Location",
                        containsString("symbols/")));
        entityManager.flush();
        String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM symbol WHERE title = ?";
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                sql, new Object[]{testTitle}, Integer.class);
        assertThat(count, is(1));
    }
```

Output logging:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /symbols
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], 
                     X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], 
                     Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], 
                     Pragma=[no-cache], 
                     Expires=[0], 
                     X-Frame-Options=[DENY], 
                     Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], 
                     WWW-Authenticate=[Basic realm="Spring"]}
         Content type = null
                 Body = 
        Forwarded URL = null
       Redirected URL = null
              Cookies = []
```

I discovered from [Spring Boot Integration Test Results in 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108765/spring-boot-integration-test-results-in-401) that I can disable security via properties with this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = { TestDataSourceConfig.class },
    properties = {
            "security.basic.enabled=false"
    })
```

but really the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)` should work, so what's blocking it?

Comment: It may not be the root cause of the problem, but your configuration is a little unusual. Why are you using `@SpringBootTest` configured to start the embedded container on a random port, yet testing with `MockMvc`? I'd either expect to see `@SpringBootTest` with a mock web environment or `@WebMvcTest` instead.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference whether I use `WebEnvironment.RANDOM` or `WebEnvironment.MOCK` although admittedly it seems more consistent to use `MOCK`. And `@WebMvcTest` gave me a lot of problems trying to get JPA to run. Similarly, `@DataJpaTest` gave me problems with `MockMvc`. I figured slicing the stack wasn't the way to go.

Comment: You either use `@SpringBootTest` which bootstraps a full application or you use the test slices, you shouldn't combine them. `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)` is to work with [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests). So in your current setup it won't work as you are bootstrapping a full application. In that case you should disable it through properties.

Comment: Are either of you prepared to make those statements into answers?

Answer (score 19):

Changing

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
```

to

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters=false)
```

works for me.

Comment: This is working for `@WebMvcTest` tests, but not for `@SpringBootTest` tests.

Answer (score 13):

Adam.

Since I also recently ran into this problem after updating **`Spring Boot`** to **`2.1.3.RELEASE`** and **`Spring Framework`** to **`5.1.4.RELEASE`**, which forces to add Spring Web Security and If someone wants to not provide security resolver then they are required to disable security in Test Environment, so I decided to share how I ended up resolving this issue.

I was also scratching head while working up an application and writing Integration Test Cases with **`@SpringBootTest`**. Using **`@WebMvcTest`** is way less painful than this, tbh.

In my case following worked.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)//This annotation was required to run it successfully
@DisplayName("UserControllerTest_SBT - SpringBootTest")
class UserControllerTest_SBT extends BaseTest_SBT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void getUsersList() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/user/listAll")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print());

    }

}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) //This is not mandatory
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false) // Secure false is required to by pass security for Test Cases
@ContextConfiguration //This is also not mandatory just to remove annoying warning, i added it
public class BaseTest_SBT {

}
```

***What didn't work:***

1-    `@SpringBootTest(properties = {"security.basic.enabled=false"})` ***<-- This solution is deprecated! [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717802/865448)***

2-    `\src\test\resources\application.properties**` -> `security.basic.enabled=false`

Hopefully, this will be helpful to someone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the year since that question, I was forced to give up searching for an answer. I find Spring great for some stuff, but I abandoned spring testing as a framework and just stuck with doing those extras by hand. Didn't take too long and frankly I didn't have the choice. It's almost impossible to work out what the problem is by following the source code due to all the annotations, and there was no real way of reducing it to the bare minimum to get it to work, as a base to build it back up to find where it broke. And that was despite comments from two Pivotal devs :(

Comment: Yeah, buddy it sucks. Even for me it was like I had to invest almost 2 full days to sort it out what could be the problem as others mentioned using property with @SpringBootTest can suffice but It was not working. Great to hear you managed to get it done other way. May be this will help other people like us who will run into problems after following outdated tutorials.

Comment: @Tejasjain glad that it was helpful for you :)

Comment: Looks good, but still does not help. `@Configuration` class is still called from `@SpringBootTest`. I am calling the endpoints with `RestTemplate, no mocking.