# MockMvc with Springboot 2.2 giving 406

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am trying to create a sample project with Springboot 2.2 & MockMvc.

Test works when end point returns String. But on change of return type to Object (JSON), it fails with 406.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
         
    
    com.example.sb22
    demo-springboot2
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    demo-springboot2
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees")
    @ResponseBody
    public Employee getAllEmployees() {
        return new Employee();
    }
 }

 // Simple class
 class Employee {
 }
```

Test file

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

public class TestControllerTest {

```
@InjectMocks
private TestController controller;

@Test
public void canReachUrl() throws Exception {
    MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    mvc
            .perform(
                    MockMvcRequestBuilders
                            .get("/employees")
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            )
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

This gives 406. Am I missing something?

Comment: I recommend against ever using `standaloneSetup` because it doesn't accurately reflect the runtime environment (security, converters, etc.). Try the exact same test with `@SpringBootTest @AutoConfigureMockMvc` and see if it works.

Comment: @chrylis Could you please direct me to a reference or example with Springboot 2.2 ?

Comment: First search result: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ (see toward the end)

Comment: remove this part `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and try once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412128/spring-boot-integration-test-ignoring-secure-false-in-autoconfiguremockmvc-annot This solved my issues!

Comment: This problem is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412128/spring-boot-integration-test-ignoring-secure-false-in-autoconfiguremockmvc-annot)