# Spring Boot: Disable security for Spring Boot Unit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test, spring-security-test

Spring Boot version: 2.0.4.RELEASE
For the Spring Boot Test below, the test returns an unwanted 401 response:
    "401" status, "error": "unauthorized"
What is the best way to disable Spring Security for the tests?
I tried a adding a configuration "security.basic.enabled=false" property like so:

```
@SpringBootTest(<br>
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,<br>
    classes = TestApp.class,<br>
    properties = {
        "security.basic.enabled=false"
})
```

And also adding this annotation to the class:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
```

But unfortunately the test still returns a "401" unauthorized error code.

Original test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
classes = App.class
)

public class ExampleTest{

@Autowired
public void setup(@LocalServerPort int port) {
    RestAssured.port = port;
}

@Test
public voidtestMethod() {
// This test code is not important to my question.     
given().log().all().get("/resources").then().log().all().statusCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST).body("error", equalTo("invalid_request")).body(not(containsString("error_reason")));
}
}
```

The class being unit tested is simple:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {
@GetMapping("/resources")
public String[] resources(
        @RequestParam("mandatory_param") String mandatory,
        @RequestParam("valid_param") @NotNull String validParam) {
    return new String[]{"1", "2"};
}
...
}
```

Does anyone know how to disable spring security for the test?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using both `@SpringBootTest` with a random port and `@AutoConfiguration` might be an issue.
Can you try:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(App.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
public class ExampleTest{}
```

or

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ExampleTest{}
```

You can event add a custom profile(**integration_test**) and make:

```
security:
      basic:
        enabled: false

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(value="integration_test")
public class ExampleTest{}
```

Update: Just found similar answer already in another SO question : [Disable security for unit tests with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169720/disable-security-for-unit-tests-with-spring-boot)

Comment: sure. Please look through the link which points to other answers. Those have been verified already as well.

Comment: This solution did not work (I had also tried stuff like this, from reading StackOverflow answers). I still get error status 401 for the below.
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes={TestApp.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyTestClass {...

Also using the WebMvcTest annotation comes up with an error, demanding you use the SpringBootTest annotation.

So, back to square one, I'm afraid. But thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: If you or any one still has some issues kindly check these posts:
(1) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412128/spring-boot-integration-test-ignoring-secure-false-in-autoconfiguremockmvc-annot

(2) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108765/spring-boot-integration-test-results-in-401