# I'm getting a java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401> when trying to do unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The Test Methods

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = RoleController.class)

class RoleControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    RoleRepoService roleRepoService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //Error I keep getting
    //java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>

    @Test
    void addRole_thenReturnsRole_andStatus200() throws Exception{
        Role manager = new Role(1,"Administrator", "Administrative Privileges");

        when(roleRepoService.saveRole(manager)).thenReturn(manager);
        this.mvc.perform(post("/addRole")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(manager)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.roleID").value("1"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.roleType").value("Administrator"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.role_description ").value("Administrative Privileges"));

        verify(roleRepoService, times(1)).saveRole(manager);

    }

    //Error I keep getting
    //java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
    @Test
    void getRoleByID_andReturnsRole__andStatus200() throws Exception {
        Role manager = new Role(1,"Administrator", "Administrative Privileges");

        when(roleRepoService.selectRoleById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(manager));

        this.mvc.perform(get("/getRole/1")
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.roleID").value("1"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.roleType").value("Administrator"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.role_description ").value("Administrative Privileges"));

        verify(roleRepoService, times(1)).selectRoleById(1);

    }
```

My **Role** POJO

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
public class Role {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(insertable = false, name = "roleID")
    private int roleID;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "roleType")
    private String roleType;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "role_description")
    private String role_description;


    public Role(@NotBlank @JsonProperty String roleType, @NotBlank @JsonProperty String role_description) {
        this.roleType = roleType;
        this.role_description = role_description;
    }

    public Role(@JsonProperty int roleID,  @NotBlank @JsonProperty String roleType,  @NotBlank @JsonProperty String role_description) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
        this.roleType = roleType;
        this.role_description = role_description;
    }


    //useful for serializing
    public Role() {
    }

    public int getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setRoleID(int roleID) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }

    public String getRoleType() {
        return roleType;
    }

    public String getRole_description() {
        return role_description;
    }


}
```

My **RoleController**

```
import com.cellulant.absalife.models.Role;
import com.cellulant.absalife.service.role.RoleRepoService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/role")
public class RoleController {

    public RoleRepoService roleRepoService;

    @Autowired
    public RoleController(RoleRepoService roleRepoService) {
        this.roleRepoService = roleRepoService;
    }

    //adds Role to database
    @PostMapping(path = "/addRole", produces = ("application/json"))
    @ResponseBody
    public Role addRole(@Valid @RequestBody @NotNull Role role){
       return roleRepoService.saveRole(role);
    }

    //gets single Role based on id
    @GetMapping(path = "/getRole/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Role> getRoleByID(@Valid @NotNull @PathVariable("id") int id){
        return roleRepoService.selectRoleById(id);
    }

    //this role should have the id in the body, otherwise it'll add a new record
    @PutMapping(path = "/updateRole")
    public Role updateRole (@Valid @NotNull @RequestBody  Role role){
       return roleRepoService.saveRole(role);
    }

    //deletes single Role based on ID
    @DeleteMapping(path = "/deleteRole/{id}")
    public void deleteRoleByID(@Valid @NotNull @PathVariable("id") int id){ roleRepoService.deleteRoleByID(id);
    }

    //gets all Role in database
    @GetMapping(path ="/getAll" )
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Role> getAllRoles(){ return roleRepoService.getAll(); }

    //deletes all Role in database
    @DeleteMapping(path = "/deleteAll")
    @ResponseBody
    public void deleteAllRoles (){roleRepoService.deleteAllRoles();}
}
```

My **WebSecurityConfigurer**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers().permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

My **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cellulant</groupId>
    <artifactId>absalife</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>absalife</name>
    <description>Absa Life USSD Implementation</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The stacktrace after a failed test run

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-26 11:54:40.514  WARN 4201 --- [           main] o.s.boot.StartupInfoLogger               : InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() took 5004 milliseconds to respond. Please verify your network configuration (macOS machines may need to add entries to /etc/hosts).
2020-03-26 11:54:45.524  INFO 4201 --- [           main] c.c.a.controllers.RoleControllerTest     : Starting RoleControllerTest on Angelas-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 4201 (started by angelamutua in /Users/angelamutua/Desktop/absalife)
2020-03-26 11:54:45.526  INFO 4201 --- [           main] c.c.a.controllers.RoleControllerTest     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-26 11:54:47.216  INFO 4201 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-26 11:54:47.542  INFO 4201 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 3c0525c4-c927-48c6-b77f-0263118021f0

2020-03-26 11:54:47.689  INFO 4201 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@53e76c11, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1697f2b3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@221a2068, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@109f8c7e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@72503b19, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3134153d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@659feb22, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@42cc183e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1192b58e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@793d163b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@49cb1baf]
2020-03-26 11:54:47.727  INFO 4201 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2020-03-26 11:54:47.727  INFO 4201 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2020-03-26 11:54:47.741  INFO 4201 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 14 ms
2020-03-26 11:54:47.777  INFO 4201 --- [           main] c.c.a.controllers.RoleControllerTest     : Started RoleControllerTest in 17.571 seconds (JVM running for 18.831)


MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /addRole
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"86"]
             Body = {"roleID":1,"roleType":"Administrator","role_description":"Administrative Privileges"}
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST=DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost/addRole]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Unauthorized
          Headers = [WWW-Authenticate:"Basic realm="Realm"", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at com.cellulant.absalife.controllers.RoleControllerTest.addRole_thenReturnsRole_andStatus200(RoleControllerTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


2020-03-26 11:54:47.992  INFO 4201 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a day now. I have tried disabling the SecurityConfiguration class in my test class, but that led to an error with the ObjectPostProcessor bean type. 
Apologies for the code dump, but I'm unsure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the url you are testing seems to be wrong consider append api/v1/role to it

Comment: Your security config does't make sense, you don't have security as you permit everything. Add `@WithAnonymousUser` to your test class or method, and make sure you have `spring-security-test` in your list of dependencies.

Comment: Yes, the permitting everything is just to test and see whether the issue may be security related.

Comment: I added the dependency as well as the annotation and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the resource you are trying to test in method `addRole_thenReturnsRole_andStatus200()` seems to be wrong.

Please try to change it to `api/v1/role/addRole` instead of only `/addRole`.

You could also consider trying first with tools like Postman, or Soap UI.

Comment: I've tested with Postman and it's fine. It's just the unit tests that are giving me a headache. I also just tried changing the url and it didn't work either

Comment: 401 status code means that the request sent by the client could not be authenticated.  try disabling the current URL being authenticated and check and give the new result put this in configure method web.ignoring().antMatchers("api/v1/role/addRole");

Comment: This answer address similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108765/spring-boot-integration-test-results-in-401